# Calculating moment of inertia for a cuboid

Tags: integration, volume

I am trying to calculate the moment of inertia tensor for a cuboid with half edges of width $a$, height $b$, depth, $c$ and mass, $m$, which according to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_moments_of_inertia), is:

\begin{equation}
I_c =\begin{bmatrix}
\dfrac{1}{12}m(b^2 + c^2) & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \dfrac{1}{12}m(a^2 + c^2) & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \dfrac{1}{12}m(a^2 + b^2) \\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

[image: \includegraphics[scale=0.25]{unitcubelabeled}]

We are summing the square distances of the infinite point masses to each rotation axis, so we use Pythagoras' Theorem to find a parametric equation of the square distance of  each point from each axis:

for x-axis:
\begin{equation}
d^2 = y^2 + z^2 \\
\end{equation}
since,
\begin{equation}
r^2 = x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \\
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
r^2 - x^2 = y^2 + z^2 \\
\end{equation}
which also intuitively makes sense as we are taking the distance from the x-axis,
and therefore doesn't have any x component.
\begin{equation}
\int_0^c \int_0^b \int_0^a   (y^2 + z^2) \hspace{0.3em} dx  \hspace{0.3em} dy \hspace{0.3em} dz
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\int_0^c \int_0^b (y^2 + z^2)a \hspace{0.3em} dy \hspace{0.3em} dz
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\int_0^c a\dfrac{1}{3}b^3 + abz^2 \hspace{0.3em} dz
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
ab\int_0^c \dfrac{1}{3}b^2 + z^2 \hspace{0.3em} dz
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
ab(\int_0^c \dfrac{1}{3}b^2  \hspace{0.3em} dz + \int_0^c  z^2  \hspace{0.3em} dz)
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{1}{3}ab^3c + \dfrac{1}{3}abc^3
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\dfrac{1}{3}abc(b^2 + c^2)
\end{equation}

similary for y-axis:
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{1}{3}abc(a^2 + c^2)
\end{equation}

and z-axis:
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{1}{3}abc(a^2 + b^2)
\end{equation}

we multiply each by $m$ by the definition of the inertia, $I = mr^2$, and align along the diagonal of the matrix.

\begin{equation}
I_c =\begin{bmatrix}
\dfrac{1}{3}m(b^2 + c^2) & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \dfrac{1}{3}m(a^2 + c^2) & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \dfrac{1}{3}m(a^2 + b^2) \\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

Can anyone see where I went wrong?

My solution seems to be off by a scalar of $\dfrac{1}{4}$ for each axis.

TIA

Comment: Can the difference be due to the fact that Wikipedia's height $h$ (or any other dimension) coincides with $2b$ where $b$ is your length (or any other)?

Comment: Hmm yes that could be it, I cant believe I didn't see that... Thanks

Comment: No.  There is no error.  Your result is the same as that found in Wikipedia, but there they use the total edge length and here you use half the lengths